# Charging a motorcycle battery with no exposed leads

Tags: motorcycle, battery, charging, battery-charger, vintage

I am trying to charge this battery with this charger:
[image]

However The connectors are as such:
[image]

The battery is 6V, 4Ah
The charger operates at 6v, 1A

Without an obvious way to connect these im a bit stuck.

How can I hook these up to charge safely?

Thanks.

Comment: You wiil have to make some wire leads to connect to the battery terminals, they are male 1/4" flat (spade) terminals, so you would need female wire end crimps and some 14 gauge wire......https://www.amazon.com/Uxcell-a12050700ux0187-Insulated-Terminal-Connector/dp/B008FZAP4S/ref=sr_1_fkmr1_4?s=industrial&ie=UTF8&qid=1528320113&sr=1-4-fkmr1&keywords=1%2F4%22+insulated+flat+spade+terminals

Answer (score 3):

Cut the ring terminals off of the charger and crimp on a pair of 1/4" female flat spade terminals, be careful to note and mark the red + lead, they need to be connected to battery in proper polarity.

Terminals you need:

https://www.napaonline.com/en/p/NW_723104

[image]